# Which one: Ubuntu 8.08, Fedora 8 or CentOS 5 for VPS hosting?

Tags: java, vps

Which one of the following distributions are better for VPS hosting (with pro/cons):

1. Ubuntu 8.04
2. Fedora 8
3. CentOS 5

I'm mostly looking for low resource usage (CPU & RAM) and easier management. Additionally I'm looking to run Java/Jetty on it.

Comment: Cent OS has a long release cycle and is pretty much the same as RHEL. The others are more targeted at the desktop. Either way this should probably be on serverfault.

Comment: I use Ubuntu 10.10 and I find its pretty low for memory usage. I would imagine all popular distributions of Linux use the same amount of resources.

Comment: Fedora 10 is also good, but Fedora 14 is the latest.

Comment: webmasters.stackexchange.com?

Comment: ubuntu 8.04 is pretty old. 10.04 is an LTS, why not go with that?

Answer (score 0):

Among the ones listed CentOS 5 is the only server distribution, other two are meant for desktops. Also Ubuntu 8.04 and Fedora 8 are not latest versions of Ubuntu or Fedora. Go for Cent OS 5 or preferably 5.5 for VPS.